# Firebase Database Rest Api : How to OrderBy with Unknown nodes

Tags: c#, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using **Firebase Database Rest Api** and I have an application to display news, and I want a way to order these news By Descending using a (Views) count for each post, At the same time,
So I am looking for a way to order all the news by (server-side) by highest views.

**My data structure is like this:**
Main/News/Categories/Education/PostId/

My json :

```
{
  "Main" : {
    "News" : {
      "Categories" : {
        "Education" : {
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifhtpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 5
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifhtp11En" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 5
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO0112ifhtpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 12
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01dxifhtpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 545
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01sdifhtpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 5
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifddhtpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 200
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifdshtpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 1
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifhtdxpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 223
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifhewtpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 451
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01idsdfhtpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 532
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2tpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 1500
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPOd01ifh2tpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 45
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh21tpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 2
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2dstpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 4
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2txpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 4
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifhds2tpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 2
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01iddfh2tpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 33
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01idxfh2tpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 52
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01idsdfh2tpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 1
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifh2tpEdsn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 1000000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to solve this process
Best regards :)

Comment: You should be able to `OrderByChild("Views").LimitToLast(10)` to get the 10 most viewed nodes. If that is not working: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Thank you for helping me :), you are a great person and I'm sorry about the image, I replaced it with JSON text You can now copy the JSON,And please I have to clarify that there is no method called (OrderByChild) because I use c# but there is OrderBy("") method and when i use it and put ("Views") An error will appear :Index not defined, add ".indexOn" my news path

Comment: The Unity/Xamarin C# SDKs have `OrderByChild` as far as I know, but if yours is a different wrapper around the REST API then `OrderBy("Views")` would be the equivalent there. The error message should explain exactly where you need to add the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to query/order by a child property through the REST API, you need to [define an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) on that property in the rules of your database.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...
    "Main": {
      "News": {
        "Categories": {
          "Education": {
            ".indexOn": "views"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If any of these node names in here are variable in your rules, you can also [use a wildcard capture variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#wildcard_capture_variables) there.

Comment: I changed the firebase database rules according to the data and use OrderBy("Views") and no error but it return first 10 only not the top 10 most views

Comment: Sorry for taking long
Yes, these posts are added by push id, I mean they are not fixed path, So do you think I should use ( use a wildcard capture) for this

Comment: As said in my initial comment to you question, you need to do `LimitToLast(10)` (or the equivalent in your library) to get the 10 highest scores. You'll likely also need to restore the 10 results in the client, as the REST results will be filtered correct, but won't be ordered (as JSON does not define an order for the keys in an object).

Comment: I gave it a try now it worked for me :) Thank you I appreciate your help for me, The problem is that I used (LimitToFirst) instead of (LimitToLast) because I expected it to get me the first highest result And thank you again because this process took me 4 days to research it

Comment: Please there is a problem that when I fetch 10 data in the beginning it will be order by views correctly but when I fetch another 10 using   **StartAt(LastId) ** and LimitToLast(10) the firebase database return 0 and this my c# code : 
public string latestid;
var data = await firebaseclient
.Child("Education")
.OrderBy("Views")
.StartAt(latestid)
.LimitToLast(10)
.OnceAsync<WorldData>();

Comment: Can you show: 1) the data that you're querying (as text again)? 2) the value of `latestid` that you pass in?

Comment: thanks for reply,i change the Json and c# code in addition the lastid string will be (-Mn7-ZxkUPOd01ifh2tpEn)

Comment: This won't work: `LastId = Data.Last().Key;`. While the results you get back from the database will be correctly filtered, they will be in an undefined order because **the keys in a JSON object have no defined order**.  You will have to sort the 10 results client-side and *then* pick the `LastId` value. I also think you'll want the **first** result, because you're using `LimitToLast`. This becomes most clear when you look at the raw REST response here: https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/70102492/Main/News/Categories/Education.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22&limitToLast=10.

Comment: I tried to get the last id by this way: `LastId = Data.First().Key;` and the **LastId** Will be **-Mn7-ZxkUPO01dxifhtpEn** but when scroll down to get another 10 elements using `.StartAt(LastId).LimitToLast(10)` it still returns null data (0) item, So what is the reason or what is the correct LastId Key or how to order the keys correctly or should I use `LimitToFirst`

Comment: I ran tests on this link (https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/70102492/Main/News/Categories/Education.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22&limitToFirst=10&StartAt=%22-Mn7-ZxkUPOd01ifh2tpEn%22) and used `Lastid`  and then `LimitToFirst` it returns data but But do you think this is the right way? because i want use `LimitToLast()` not `LimitToFirst()`

Comment: Neither `Data.First()` nor `Data.Last()` will work, since the keys in the JSON result are **unordered**. By now I recommend opening a new question though, with its own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for your help in this matter, I have posted the question with code